# swift MVVM viewModel items contain too much information for tableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

My tableViewController has viewModel, items ( array of model ) of which should be binded to tableView ( tableView.rx.bind... ), but i don't want tableView to know too much about data model, i would like it to know only about ui version of this model ( like simpler struct with only few parameters ), but I don't know what to do so viewModel could do what he wants with full model and tableView knew only about ui model.
I wanted to try something like this, but in this case i can't manipulating with original data, only with ui version of model.

```
struct MediaFile: Codable {
    var url: String
    var title: String
    var id: String
    var duration: TimeInterval
    var author: String
    var videoURL: URL
    var supportsVideo: Bool = false
    var videoDescription: String?
    var imgURL: URL?
}

struct MediaFileUIModel {
    var title: String
    var duration: TimeInterval
    var author: String
    
    init(mediaFile: MediaFile) {
        self.title = mediaFile.title
        self.duration = mediaFile.duration
        self.author = mediaFile.author
    }
}

class PlaylistViewModel: PlaylistViewModelProtocol {

    var uiModels: RxRelay.BehaviorRelay<[MediaFileUIModel]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [MediaFileUIModel]())
    
    var player: MusicPlayerProtocol
    
    var saver: MediaSaverProtocol
    
    init(player: MusicPlayerProtocol, saver: MediaSaverProtocol) {
        self.player = player
        self.saver = saver
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        uiModels.accept(saver.dataManager.fetchAllMedia().map({ MediaFileUIModel.init(mediaFile: $0)} ))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide an interface that's needed for your UI instead of defining the new type

```
protocol MediaFileUIModelProtocol {
  var title: String { get set }
  var duration: TimeInterval { get set }
  var author: String { get set }
}

extension MediaFile: MediaFileUIModelProtocol {}
```

And update your view model, respectively

```
class PlaylistViewModel: PlaylistViewModelProtocol {
  var uiModels: RxRelay.BehaviorRelay<[MediaFileUIModelProtocol]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [MediaFileUIModelProtocol]())
  private var models: RxRelay.BehaviorRelay<[MediaFile]> = BehaviorRelay(value: [MediaFile]())

  func fetchData() {
    models.accept(saver.dataManager.fetchAllMedia()
  }
}
```

And then just bind models updates to the UI models